# MS Surface Keyboard Cover not recognized by MS Surface Pro 3

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-surface-pro-3

My Surface Pro 3 cover mysteriously stopped working (other USB keyboards work).

I’ve exhausted all of the steps from the Internet and am hoping for some advice here on what to try next.

- Clean the metal pins on both the keyboard and the Surface Pro 3 with alcohol swap and q-tip.
- Performed the standard two button shutdown procedure - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4036280/surface-force-a-shut-down-and-restart-your-surface
- Update "HID keyboard" device in Device Manager.
- Uninstall and reinstall "HID keyboard device" in Device Manager.
- Removed HID keyboard device in Device Driver and manually installed Surface Type Cover device (which later automatically turns to "HID keyboard device" when you hit "update drivers")
- Updated all Windows 10 patches to date.
- Tried a brand new keyboard (Microsoft FMM-00001 Type Cover for Surface Pro [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073W4MPJF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073W4MPJF)  )
- Updated firmware for Surface Pro 3 (typed in “winver”, took that Windows version, then downloaded the specific patch required here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38826)
- Reset Surface Pro 3 while keeping personal files
- Reset Surface Pro 3 and deleted all personal files
- Performed hardware tests on aka.ms/surfacerepair (nothing bad found; all looks ok)
- Drained the battery most of the way before connecting again - the two times it worked momentarily these last few days was when I connected my new type cover keyboard to the Surface Pro 3 after the battery had died down to below 50%; a simple reboot later, everything stopped working. This user seems to have the same problem with it working briefly when there is low battery - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/surface-pro-3-battery-drain-along-with-type-cover/52f983c6-2e53-49fa-aac6-7c4cc5d25d9f  )

A breakdown of the steps I've done to sometimes get it working

- Leave Surface Pro 3 on about 2 hours on battery only.
- Power on Surface Pro 3.
- Working Keyboard.
- Turn off Surface Pro 3 (or reboot)
- Keyboard not working anymore
- Another similar user here - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/surface-3-type-cover-issue/2d6ed60a-c892-4ed9-907f-846fd9496f5a

Can anyone recommend any other troubleshooting steps? One of these steps seemed to work ok for others having this same problem.